# Douglas fir stair treads spots not staining?

Tags: staining

I made these stair treads out of reclaimed Douglas fir. The wood is gorgeous! Some of the stairs stained amazing and a couple have these much lighter spots where the wood didn't seem to take the stain?

Did I mess up with my process or is this just how Douglas fir works? How  is it suppose to look? First time working with reclaimed wood.

Process:

1. Sanded 80 grit- I read not to go higher than 80 to help the grain pop?
2. 50/50 denatured alcohol/shellac
3. Minwax gel stain coffee

[image][image][image]

I love the markings and chose the darker color with the intention of getting them to stand out. I edited my pics and circled the spots I’m talking about. It’s these spots that came out even lighter that I don’t know about.

Comment: Those look like tool marks, possible from the original milling. Did you actually prepare these so that they were flat? 80 grit seems rather coarse. Did you get down to less aged material? High spots will often take more of a gel stain.

Comment: As in planing them? No. I was told by a friend it wasn’t necessary. I’m am brand new to working with reclaimed wood. I thought I got down to less aged. However I was afraid of going to far and messing up the saw mill markings. Would it be better to re sand these pieces down again and start over? Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Those markings represent raised material, and by staining it you highlighted those marks. Folks here could probably suggest how you could reduce the contrast if you don't like the look, but to some extent this is what these sorts of stains do: highlight grain, spalling, nail holes, and the like. It becomes a matter of preference: to what extent do you want the beat-up wood to reflect how beat-up it is. A finer prep and (maybe) a thinner or lighter stain would both lead to less contrast.

Comment: Turn the question around: assume you have some reclaimed lumber you like the look of, and you want to use it in some project. To what extent do you want the surface damage to be highlighted, and how smooth of a finish do you want? People here would be able to tell you how to do that.

Comment: Maybe I’m not stating my question properly. I love the markings and chose the darker color with the intention of getting them to stand out. I edited my pics and circled the spots I’m talking about. It’s these spots that came out even lighter that I don’t know about.

Comment: The lighter areas are just where the wood is smoother. The 'stain' (gel stain is coloured varnish, not true stain) simply collected in recesses and can't colour the smoother areas as much with the way you applied it. *"I read not to go higher than 80 to help the grain pop?"* This makes no sense to me, can you recall where you read that? It's different if you want to retain an aged/weathered look to reclaimed wood but normally you'd never stop at 80 and even 120 would be considered a little on the coarse side.

Comment: Thank you for responding! It sounds like I need to the up more on sanding. It was either a video I watched or a blog post I read. The guy had said to really make the sawmill marks show and “grain pop” to not sand past 80 grit.  my bad. I just was researching the best ways to make the markings darker then the rest of the wood when I stained it. Like I said I’m not afraid to admit I’m a newbie. I’ve only ever worked with pine for small projects. I mean you have to learn somewhere right? Any suggestions on where to read reliable info? Can I sand down and start over?

Comment: Not your bad, you're only starting out and everyone is at the mercy of the stuff they read or watch. Grain 'pop' is used variably by different people (clearly, as the guy obviously wasn't using it the way I would!) but I think he was referring more to the marks, not wood grain or figure (other markings or colour variations in in the wood) as most people understand it to mean. Stlll doesn't make sense to me but never mind. So back to your treads, the thing with this is you can't sand more without reducing the sawblade marks which you want to keep, correct?

Comment: *"Any suggestions on where to read reliable info?"* Here's not a bad place to start out with 4yrs of past Q&As. Lots of decent books on woodworking, some going back to the 19th century. In terms of mags Fine Woodworking and Popular Woodworking are probably both worth a look, although FW may have the edge (larger format is nice too). But PW has Bob Flexner writing for it and he's one of three go-to guys for stuff to do with finishing, the other two being Michael Dresdner and Jeff Jewitt. There are other authors of finishing books but I think you're safe with anything those three have written.

Comment: Just one thing I wanted to say about finishing because it's my bag.... finishing doesn't have to be complicated! People make it complicated by combining things needlessly but at heart it's a simple process that doesn't require a chest full of supplies. So I would advise keeping it very simple to begin with and not try this, that and the other thing. Start with three or four basics, learn how to use them *well* in a variety of different ways and a lot of the fads and commercial blended finishes (e.g. "Danish oil", "teak oil finish") will be of little interest, saving you money and time. [contd]

Comment: So you have shellac already, that's great as it's a superb finish in its own right that can be used in numerous ways, and a useful tool (sealer, intermediate coat). Gloss oil-based poly would be my top recommendation as a must-have (my 2c, avoid Minwax, almost always the least good option) and like shellac it's very versatile, can be used dilute and thin, at full strength and everything in between. Once you get into working with hardwoods I'd add in boiled linseed oil, which can be used solo and mixed to make your own blended finishes at a fraction of the cost of the shop-bought. [contd]

Comment: Now colouring. You've used "gel stain" already so advise you continue with that before you try other colouring options. "Gel stain" is not stain in the conventional sense, it's jellied coloured varnish. But it's a useful colouring tool and particularly well suited to softwood so very good for beginners. Once you start working in hardwoods you have more colour options available from the native colour of the woods. But if you want to colour stuff further you can experiment with true stains/dyes at that point (which generally work better on hardwoods) which can be used with "gel stain" if needed.

Comment: @Graphus, this might be another place where a short answer based on your comments ("The lighter areas are just where the wood is smoother.") actually answers the specific question. Unless you can refer to another Q&A that covers this (probably answered by you...) I've already edited the question to make it clear that the query is about why the "stain" didn't take in some places...

Answer (score 3):

In my judgement, from seeing your pictures, I would not be concerned about the spots that you have highlighted as being lighter. Those spots appearing to be in areas where the wood has become smoother due to the sanding process. The overall look if you stand back and consider what character the used lumber offers I would just accept those minor  light spots as just another part of the character.

After all if you had wanted a more perfect and consistent finish you would have planed these boards down to a smooth finish that removed all the original circular saw marks and random scratches and gouges. And even then fir will still have variations in the way it takes stain!

Comment: Additionally, the lighter spots (only the one in the 3rd picture really stands out to me - I probably wouldn't have noticed the others without the circles) simply seem to indicate wear on the stair tread, making them look like they've been there a long time.